# What's the verb for 'to form a canonical representation'?

Tags: single-word-requests, programming

I'd like to describe the activity of turning a set of elements into its canonical ([standardized base](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34920/what-does-canonical-mean)) form.

Some candidates seem to be:

- canonicalize
- canonize

I'd also like to name the device performing this action, candidates so far:

- canonicalizer
- canonizer

None of these look *quite* right, what's the right term?

Comment: Related: [“Normalization” vs. “canonicalization”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35860/). I think this is really something you should probably take to programmers.se

Comment: @FumbleFingers Programmers better ask linguists before taking the English lexicon into their hands, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always use ***canonize*** myself, because it’s short to type and accords with canon law.

You could also use *normalize* or *standardize*, both of which are preferable to the wholly asquerous *regularize*, a sad and overburdened word brought to you by the unregulated coiners.

Probably *beatify* isn’t going far enough, though. :)

The thing that does it is a *normalizer*, if you don’t care for *canonizer* or *pope*.

Comment: I think “canonicalization” is probably more of a highly specialised term that doesn't overlap in meaning with "canonize".

Comment: "Canonize" has too much religious association ('declare someone a saint').

Comment: @Mitch I know it has a lot of religious association, but better than than neologuing uselessly hyperoverextended words terminating in a clattering cavalcade  of multiple derivationalistic suffixes. You just can’t take these things too seriously. People use ‘bless’ in a corporate sense without worrying about their local priest.

Comment: What does "asquerous" mean?

Comment: @jwpat7 ***Asquerous*** means icky, gross, disgusting, repugnant, repulsive, noisome, nauseating, vomitous — scabby in a suppurating way. It’s from Latin *eschara* for a scab or scar, from Greek *εσχαρα* for hearth, brazier, scab. It’s related to the medical term *eschar*, and of course to the normal word *scar*, but has much more of a gross-me-out connotation. If you have Spanish-speaking friends, they’ll say ‘¡Me da asco!’ for ‘Ewww, gross!’, which has the same Latin/Greek origin.

Comment: So I'm going to go with 'canonize', working from the root word, despite the computing use here...mostly because I feel like taking a stand and partially because uttering 'canonicalizer' is atrocious.

Answer (score 12):

In computing contexts, the standard verb is definitely *canonicalize*. Its agent noun is *canonicalizer*, though that's not as common as the verb itself.

Hence, from assorted RFCs and W3C technical reports:

> To **canonicalize** an element including its namespaces, attributes, and content, the node-set must actually contain all of the nodes corresponding to these parts of the document, not just the element node. [[link](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3076.txt)]
>
> The "include" and "exclude" SigData fields modify the default behavior of the label **canonicalizer**. [[link](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DSig-label/)]
>
> On first glance it would seem a simple enough exercise to **canonicalize** the XML encoded query and then insert it into the query portion of the URL. [[link](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3368.txt)]
>
> Any XML document, say X, processed by a **canonicalizer**, will produce an XML Document X'. [[link](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-xml-canonical-req)]
>
> However, designers of applications, protocols, or specifications are encouraged to use the information from the IANA Language Subtag Registry to support **canonicalizing** language tags and ranges in order to map grandfathered and obsolete tags or subtags into modern equivalents. [[link](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4647.txt)]

(And, you didn't ask for this, but the action noun is *canonicalization*.)

Comment: I think you’ll find ***canon-ic-al-iz-at-ion*** to be one of those overly academic words that collapses under its own weight: the poor thing has **five** derivational suffixes smacked onto its sorry end. One is ok; two are tolerable if necessary; but five is beyond the pale. It sounds stuffy and pretentious. A native speaker would use a shorter and more convenient word. And yes, I’m a professional computer scientist, so I happen to know whereof I speak on this.  It collapses under a clattering cavalcade of catenated coprocessizationalizing fooishnessesesses.

Comment: @tchrist: Of course you know whereof you speak, since you speak only of your own opinion. (Everybody's got one.) As a native English speaker and a professional programmer, I'm not inclined to be cowed by your stated credentials, sorry. And your count of derivational affixes is somewhat debatable, since *-ical* and *-ation* are functioning here as single units. But your opinion is perfectly valid, and I don't intend to denigrate it. I even half-agree with it. But only half. ;-)

Comment: The reason *-ical* and *-ation* count as two each is because of minimal pairs like *historic/historical* and *hyphenate/hyphenation*.

Comment: For the verb I'm using canonicalizes.